# Getting ids of xml layout

Tags: android

Im working at a little Annotation Processor for android.

I have the following scenario:
I have a xml layout resource id and I want to find all views in this xml layout. I simply want to parse the xml layout file to retrieve some information that I will use later on.

Does anybody know if such a tool exists or how to implement something like this?

I know it's not simple. There are serval things to consider like:

1. same layout files in different layout-resource folders like:

   - res/layout/mylayout.xml
   - res/layout-xlarge/mylayout.xml

   I want to parse both mylayout.xml files.
2. I only have the resource id (integer) of a layout, how do I map that back to the xml file (String, name)

Any suggestion how to start?

I doubt I can use Android classes, because I want to write an Annotation Processor. AnnotationProcessing runs in it's own jvm before compiling Android resources.

From what I understand the workflow should be as follows:

1. Map id (integer) to layout file name (String). I guess I have to
   parse the R.java class to achieve that.
2. Next I have to check
   recursively all layout resource folders to find the corresponding
   layout.xml files.
3. Parsing the xml files (no big deal)

Comment: Have you tried simple xml parsing? just curious! i guess it should work?

Comment: Yeah, thats exactly what I want to do. I have updated my question.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/XMLReader.html or http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html (not sure about sax) or http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html (PullParser)

Answer (score 0):

if you need the name of the resources that correspond to a particular id, you can use

```
String getResourceEntryName(int id)
```

that is a method of `Resources()`. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceEntryName%28int%29) you can find the documentation

Comment: It's a good starting point, but I doubt I can use Android classes, because I want to write an Annotation Processor. AnnotationProcessing runs in it's own jvm before compiling Android.

Comment: I guess so. Im not sure if R.java will be generated before starting compiling, but I think it will generated everytime I save a file (in Android Studio). So I guess I have to "parse" R.java to get the name (I have updated my question to illustrate a simple workflow). Any better approach is welcome.

Comment: More then parsing you will probably use the reflection to get a map of the R's content

Comment: Good idea! I knew I will find smart people on StackOverflow